# Laravel - How to CRUD records with ownership?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I've multiple users - Admin, Manager, User. User can CRUD records owned by him. Manager can CRUD records owned by him and his Users. Admin can CRUD records of all. How to achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: use their role and the role of user they want to edit

Comment: Any sample code?

Comment: You have hierarchy of users and their access levels.
This is a broad thing to give sample code

Comment: User1 has Record1 and Record2 and User2 has Record3 and Record4. User1 can access only his records, whereas Manager can access records of both User1 and User2 and same for Admin. How to replicate this in Laravel code?

Comment: You can define a separate role table with id and name. which contains records like 1 admin, 2 Manager , 3 user.  And then in user table add column called role_id as foreign key on role table. After this you can just check role of current user and role of user whose details you want to edit.

Comment: @Sagar I already have roles table and defined. I can display the records of a particular user when he is logged in, as records has owner_id. But how to display the records of both users when a Manager is logged in and same case if Admin is logged, I want to display records of all Managers and Users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one role use middleware.

If you have multiple roles just like you are saying you have use gates/policies provided by Laravel out of the box.

To handle admin you will use before filter

```
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    return ($user->is_admin) ? true : null; //return null so we continue authorising further
}
```

To handle manager || user you will use something along these lines (most tricky one):

```
public someCRUDaction(User $current, Item $item) {
    return $item->created_by == $current->id || $current->users->contains('id', $item->created_by); // you need to handle logic if item belongs to manager
}
```

> **Note**: `$item->created_by == $current->id` is self explanatory and handles if current user is owner of item

---

How to use policies (I would go with policies) and gates:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-policies

Remember that you don't want to validate anything just simply can `$current` user do action X?

Using policies you will need to check if user can do action X at least two times (in views and in controllers/routes/customized form requests - where you handle validation).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware which verify the role of the current user and the role of the selected user for the action.